# xslt: move child node to parent

Tags: xslt

My goal is to give access to certain attributes of element "p" (as new children elements) while putting the rest of the original content to a new sibling child "p1", and then to come back to the **original** structure after editing has been done.

So the original nodes look like this:

```
<p attr1="..." attr2="..." moreattr1="..." moreattr2="...">...content,more nodes,etc...</p>
```

My "editable" structure is this:

```
<p>
   <attr1edit value="...">
   <attr2edit value="...">
   <p1 moreattr1="..." moreattr2="...">...content,more nodes...</p1>
</p>
```

"p1" has now taken all the content of former "p" except the leading attribute-elements.

I am stuck at this point when I try to get back to the **original** structure:

I can put the attributes (attr1,attr2) back in place in "p1" together with the other attributes, but then I do not know how to swap the whole content of "p1" back to "p" and delete the "p1", or delete "p" and rename "p1" to "p" (which would move the node one step up). 
How can this be done? 
Thank you very much - Chris

Comment: Which XSLT version do you use?  Are you trying to do this all in one stylesheet? Or do you want to chain transformation? It is not clear to me why you need the editable structure if the final result is a different one. Generally if you need temporary data inside of one transformation you can do that easily with XSLT 2.0 as long as you separate transformation steps by using modes.

Answer (score 2):

The stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::p1)] | p1/@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="p1/node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{substring-before(name(), 'edit')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<p>
   <attr1edit value="..."/>
   <attr2edit value="..."/>
   <p1 moreattr1="..." moreattr2="...">...content,more nodes...</p1>
</p>
```

into

```
<p attr1="..." attr2="..." moreattr1="..." moreattr2="...">...content,more nodes...</p>
```

Comment: Dear Martin, you are right, this is not easy to "understand".

Comment: Dear Martin, ... Taking out certain attributes and modifying the structure is to improve visibility. Of course, not in XML, but in a layout software, where more features are added like prefixes displayed in coloured type, etc. Unfortunately the parser only works with XSLt version 1. Thank you very much for your effort, your coding was quite instructive (although not 100% applicable) -- best regard -- Chris